# Strange Netbeans IDE behaviour in Ubuntu (PHP Development)

Tags: php, ubuntu, netbeans

I have been using Netbeans as my PHP IDE. I downloaded the netbeans from netbeans site and extracted it to the folder /opt/ and then I executed it by using

```
$ sudo /opt/netbeans-7.1.2/bin/./netbeans
```

It seems to load. The splash screen shows up and in the splash screen it gets the message, done loading modules. After which I was supposed to get a Fully loaded Netbeans IDE. But I get nothing. The Netbeans seems loading but I didn't get any graphical screen, seems like the GUI of Netbeans had been totally hidden, but the process for netbeans as seen is in progress. I verified its execution using

```
$ ps -aux | grep netbeans
```

which shows the process is actually has been loaded successfully.

I have been trying to resolve this issue and have already tried to change few parameters in netbeans.conf.

I am looking for help, suggestions, guesses. What might have caused this problem.

Comment: this seems to be a problem with your java runtime. try the JRE from java.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. It seems there was some mis-configuration which caused this problem. I delete the "~/.netbeans/7.1.2" and then restarted the netbeans.

My version of Netbeans is 7.1.2. So to delete the folder I used the command listed below.

```
$ rm -rf ~/.netbeans/7.1.2
```

If you have multiple instances of netbeans then you'll have to find the right folder to delete.

It worked fine and I got the netbeans GUI Back. I think I messed some configuration. Restarting netbeans re-created the folder.

@Jan : Thanks for answer. I have already been using jre, jdk from java.com.